# HTTP Error 404.15 - Not Found while exporting crystal report mvc4

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, crystal-reports

I am able to view the report(crystal report) in ASP.NET mvc (aspx view) without any error

But when I export the report to either PDF or other format, the

**HTTP Error 404.15 - Not Found**

**The request filtering module is configured to deny a request where the query string is too long.**

why its sending query string while exporting?

Answer (score 1):

HTTP Error 404.15 - Not Found
The request filtering module is configured to deny a request where the query string is too long.

Most likely causes:

> Request filtering is configured on the Web server to deny the request
>   because the query string is too long.

Things you can try:

> Verify the
>   configuration/system.webServer/security/requestFiltering/requestLimits@maxQueryString
>   setting in the applicationhost.config or web.config file.

```
<configuration>
<system.webServer>
<security>
<requestFiltering>
<requestLimits maxUrl="10999" maxQueryString="2097151" />
</requestFiltering>
</security>
</system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Comment: @satyender <requestLimits maxUrl="10999" maxQueryString="2097151" />

Comment: i have tried this than i am getting this error. The length of the query string for this request exceeds the configured maxQueryStringLength value.

Comment: i have tried to increase this maxQueryString upto max

Comment: @satyender can you post your webconfig?

Comment: <security>
      <requestFiltering>
        <requestLimits maxQueryString="500000000" maxUrl="65536" maxAllowedContentLength="500000000" ></requestLimits>
      </requestFiltering>
    </security>